# How to process opencv command from command line to only use GPU

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, gpu, haar-classifier

*I am not sure whether this question would go on this community. But I don't know anywhere else, so...*

I am trying to run `opencv_traincascade` command in ubuntu terminal. I have a GPU installed in my pc.

I have checked that when I run the said command, the CPU usage goes 400% and the GPU usage also goes up to 20%.

What can I do to use only GPU for this purpose?

Here are my system info:

```
sudo lshw -C display 
  *-display                                                                                                                                                                           
       description: VGA compatible controller                                                                                                                                         
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
lspci | grep VGA 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f82 (rev a1)
```

PS:- the command is :
`opencv_traincascade -data xyz -vec xyz.vec -bg xyz.txt -numPos abcxyz -numNeg abcxyz -numStages 5 -featureType LBP`

Comment: I think if Opencv GPU drivers were available at the time of installing OpenCV, then it should automatically defer the tasks to GPU wherever possible. Not all computations are optimized for GPU, so there would some usage of CPU if you do that correctly as well.

Comment: According to [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html), it says **` Otherwise, the module is still built but at runtime `**. I don't understand how it is to be done on the ubuntu terminal...

Comment: Also I am trying to reinstall opencv `WITH-CUDA =ON` but getting error as `OpenCV is not able to find/configure CUDA SDK (required by WITH_CUDA).

  CUDA support will be disabled in OpenCV build.`

Comment: Yeah you are on the right track. You need to pass the `WITH-CUDA=ON` while installing OpenCV. I think you should follow some other thread which shows how to properly install CUDA.